# How do I get the siteName in a module (Craft 3)

Tags: craft3, modules, globals

In templates I can do something like `{{siteName}}`. But how do I retrieve this in a module?

I've tried:

`Craft::$app->config->siteName`

I can grab my custom globals via `Craft::$app->globals`, but the class reference doesn't say anything about the defaults like `siteName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When searching the Craft 3.5.x docs for `siteName`, I see references to `Global Variables` and `General Config Settings`. Screenshot: https://cln.sh/egvIXhxZSzaFjeCgNLxX

However, AFAICT, it works differently for modules/plugins. As per the Sites section in the Craft 3.5.x Class Reference docs at https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-sites.html, you would do something like one of the following:

```php
Craft::$app->sites->currentSite->name;
Craft::$app->sites->primarySite->name;
Craft::$app->sites->getSiteByHandle('default')->name;
Craft::$app->sites->getSiteById(1)->name;
```

I'm getting the `name` part because I'm using PhpStorm with autocomplete set up as per article at https://nystudio107.com/blog/auto-complete-craft-cms-3-apis-in-twig-with-phpstorm

Screenshot of autocomplete in action: https://cln.sh/T77W1Y69SmR3qPUPv0sb

I'm successfully using `Craft::$app->sites->getSiteById(1)->name;` in one of my custom modules.

Comment: Much appreciated! I never used multiple sites before, so I didn't even think of having to access it by current site. thank you thank you!!

Comment: In support of this answer, the `siteName` Twig global is just a shortcut to the current site's `->name`. See https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/de7fbb5043e4d5da4b3fb5030c3882188e201c0e/src/web/twig/Extension.php#L1312

Comment: And in more support of this answer, `siteName` and `siteUrl` have been [deprecated from 3.6](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/3.6/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated) :)

Comment: @Oli So I SHOULD actually just use the `Craft::$app->config->general->siteName` and not what setting is in the CP?

Comment: @good_afternoon: You can see [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/de7fbb5043e4d5da4b3fb5030c3882188e201c0e/src/web/twig/Extension.php#L1312) from the source code how the ``siteName`` twig variable is being set. As mentioned in the answer,  ``Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->name`` will be equivalent.

Comment: The thing [deprecated](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/3.6/src/config/GeneralConfig.php#L1233) is setting ``siteUrl`` and ``siteName`` from [``config/general.php``](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html) so you should avoid calling the config class where it gets the data from.